# How to redirect domain.tld/fr/anything to domain.tld/FR/anything?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website setup at mydomain.com/FR

I'd like to make sure people typing

- mydomain.com/fr are being sent to mydomain.com/FR
- mydomain.com/fr/aNyTHiNg are being sent to mydomain.com/FR/anything

... whether they type http, https or http(s)://www.

How would I do that using .htaccess ? I'm afraid this is too much of a complex rule for me to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^fr(/.*)?$ FR$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Wouldn't it be a problem if url is like domain.tld/fr/french-fries ?

Comment: `domain.tld/fr/french-fries` will be rewritten to `domain.tld/FR/french-fries` as you want.